# specify one file for handlebars compiler

Tags: javascript, webstorm, handlebars.js

I'm trying to setup a watchfile in webstorm.

I want to precompile one file into my main `templates.js` aggregate file.

Is this possible?

If I use `/path/to/hello.tpl -f templates.js` option it just overwrites all my other templates in the `templates.js` file.

If I use `/path/to/templates > templates.js` that means I have to precompile every single template in my filewatcher when I modify just one template.

Edit:

If you pass a directory, and redirect its output to a file, you can get all precompiled templates in one file. `handlebars -e tpl ./templates/ > ./js/templates.js`

This will precompile all `./templates/*.tpl` files and save them to `./js/templates.js` which you can then include in your page.

Here's some more info about the technique:
http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro

Comment: I have a doubt, usually I used a **one to one mapping** template and js.  However you're having a different approach like **many to one** templates and js.  Can you please share some tutorials/ blogs to get a deep understanding.

Comment: Thank you, I marked as fav since started learning handlebar.js.  Looks like I haven't enough done.  I will delete my answer, within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nodejs plugin which exactly does what you want and more. Please try this out and see if it suits you.

https://github.com/cif/handlebar-rider

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to slightly modify the handlebars module itself so in node_modules\handlebars\bin\handlebars find the processTemplate function and change

```
if (extension.test(path) || fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()) {
    processTemplate(path, root || template);
  }
```

to

```
if (extension.test(path) || /\.hbr$/.test(path)|| fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()) {
    processTemplate(path, root || template);
  }
```

which then takes all your template files (that I gave an hbr extension) and puts them in the file specified by the -f flag.